# Step halving factor reduced below minimum in PNLS step

Tags: r, nlme

I am running a self-starting logistic model in nlme, and have received the classic error message:

```
Error in nlme.formula(model = MASS.CUL ~ SSlogis(GD10C, Asym, xmid, scal),  : 
step halving factor reduced below minimum in PNLS step
```

I first put in the code:

```
shortG <- groupedData(MASS.CUL ~ GD10C | Expu2, data = short)
nlsL <- nlsList(MASS.CUL ~ SSlogis(GD10C, Asym, xmid, scal) , data = shortG)
shortG.nlme <- nlme(nlsL, random=pdDiag(Asym + xmid + scal ~ 1))
```

Everything worked fine.  Then I went to standardize the variance with the code:

```
shortG.nlmeb <- update(shortG.nlme, weights = varPower())
```

This was where I got the error message.  Now, normally I can fit a square peg in a round hole with this by simply increasing the pnlsTol.  However, after increasing it first to 0.01, then to 0.1, then to 1, then to 10, then to 10,000 just for fun, I keep getting the error message.  This is leading me to believe that something is wrong apart from the just the pnls halving factor.  Does anyone have a clue of what could be causing this error?

Comment: This probably can't be answered without access to the data.

Comment: BTW, a rather extended example of using `nlme`/`nlmer`/AD Model Builder to fit a mixed nonlinear model is [here](https://rpubs.com/bbolker/3423)